# The connection between Spring, AngularJS and Maven

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, maven

I am starting a new job this fall, and I need to learn a bit about Maven, Spring and Angular before I start. I am fresh out of studies, and I have never used or heard about these tools before. I have read a bit about all three, but feel none the wiser.

Could someone give an easy explanation on what these three are used for, and what the connection between them are? I guess that there must be one since I have been asked to learn all three. Also, from what I could understand Angular use HTML and CSS, is this something I should learn before using Angular?

Comment: A Build tool, a backend and a frontend framework. The only possible connection can be done by the tool selection of the project.

Comment: Did you read the `info` pages of any of these three technologies on this Site? Hover over the tag and click `info`. This question is way too broad.

Comment: Introduction sections of the respective Wikipedia pages provide an _easy explanation_ in general.

Comment: If you are new with Spring, I really recommed start to read about Spring Boot: http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/ . From the official site:  "We take an opinionated view of the Spring platform and third-party libraries so you can get started with minimum fuss."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS is a JavaScript framework, the aim is to work with HTML pages and CSS. Pure HTML pages produces static web pages, the CSS is used to bring some style (colors, positioning...) to the web page with that pure HTML code, then AngularJS puts some life to the page, turning that static page in a dynamic web page, that makes possible change the content of the page dynamically etc.
So if you want to learn about AngularJS you'll need to learn at least HTML.

Spring is a Java Framework, which has the role of backend to web applications. He gets the data from the frontend (AngularJS + HTML and CSS) and does something nice with that, most commonly he processes the data and puts on a database, for instance.

Maven brings a project's structure to life (thanks to Broser's comment). He manages the dependencies of all the things you want to use on your project, useful for the build process too. Maven does a lot of things related to dependencies and packaging. So Maven can help you on the dependencies of Spring Framework, for instance.

Further information about this technologies, you can find in the official page of each of them.

Helpful links:

> HTML: w3schools.com/html/default.asp
>
> CSS:  w3schools.com/css/default.asp and 
>   w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp (nice to learn)
>
> JavaScript:  www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp
>
> AngularJS: docs.angularjs.org/misc/started
>
> Maven: 
>   https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html
>
> Spring: 
>   http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview-getting-started-with-spring.html

From JavaScript contents I recommend you to search for at least one good book for each one.

Comment: Thank you so much for an explanation that is easy to understand! I have never encountered any of them, and the explanations on the official sites were a bit too complicated for me ;-)

Comment: Objection! Your honor! ;-) Maven is _not_ responsible for organizing the structure of an application. ! as a SW designer am. Maven "just" brings a project's structure to life. Though it does this extremly well.

Comment: @GeroldBroser you're right! Thank you for contribute. Already edited.

Answer (score 1):

[Spring](http://spring.io/) is an enterprise JVM framework, which offers things like [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), [aspect-oriented programming](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html),  and offers a premier [MVC model](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).  It is primarily written in Java, with a notable exception being the JSP files - those are written typically with [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/).

[Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) is a [dependency management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) and [build management](https://maven.apache.org/run-maven/index.html) tool, which has the capabilities of running a project's test suite in addition to building and producing JARs or deployable WARs for releases.

[Angular](https://angularjs.org/) is a JavaScript framework which can be used to control what is rendered on the screen, and also affect presentation.

---

There's a lot about these to take in, and I wouldn't expect a weekend to do it for you.  However, the general approach to these projects is to think about them in *layers*.

Given that concept...

- Spring is the backend layer; it is handling much of the heavy lift with regard to the business logic and processing of data
- Angular is the frontend layer; it handles interaction with the user
- Maven is divorced from both layers yet can play a role in both (depending on how it's set up); it governs how the project is built and what resultant artifacts are made to be published to production